# Linking Conan Include to VS Code

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm currently using Conan on a C++ project using `sqlite_orm` as a dependency.

When using my personal include (like `myClass.hpp` for example) Visual Studio Code is able to provide auto-completion but with Conan's include, no auto-completion is possible.

I'm looking for a way to link the include path of Conan to my VSCode, any idea?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your CMake files to show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the following line in your project's `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file

`"includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "~/.conan/data/**"]`

Comment: Works but requires a restart of VSCode.

Comment: For me it worked with vscode 1.48.0 without restarting. Thanks for this

Comment: Doesn't work on windows. `C:/.conan` is the directory and it doesn't contain `data` .

Comment: Oh and `~/.conan/data` doesn't contain any header files, they are all located in `C:/.conan/somehash/1/include`

Comment: But adding `C:/.conan/**` doesn't work either. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1213

Comment: I'm gonna stick with VS19/CLion until this is fixed.

Comment: for windows in JSON config file for all cpp projects `"C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**","${env:USERPROFILE}/.conan/data/**"]`

Comment: With the new conan2: `~/.conan2/**` this works.

Answer (score 14):

Add `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt (or add to cmake: `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ..`) so a [`build/compile_commands.json`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) will be generated.

VS Code (clion, etc) can utilize this file to support auto complete:

```
$ cat .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
    }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, also for anyone trying this I think you should be aware that some versions may differ, so please check down your build folder for the compile_commands.json file an then specify the correct path :)

Answer (score 3):

Conan doesn't provide an extension for vscode yet, but you can try:

https://github.com/FIREFOXCYBER/conan-tools-vs-code

It's available on marketplace.

Otherwise, you can add manually the package folder path (e.g. `~/.conan/data/package/version/package/package_id/include`) in your settings.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of [dvorak4tzx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70616885/14325545)'s and [spanishgum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65930468/14325545)'s answers, combined with VS Code's option for [Customizing default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp) is the following option:

Generate a `build/compile_commands.json` eiter by adding to CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

or on the command line:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
```

And then insert into `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
"C_Cpp.default.compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
```

Note: I experienced trouble if

```json
"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
```

was part of the `c_cpp_properties.json`. Without it, the IntelliSense works as expected.

I would argue that `"includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "~/.conan/data/**"]` is not desired, as you may have many versions of each library beneath `~/.conan/data`.

---

Sources:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-get-intellisense-to-work-correctly
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables

Answer (score 2):

After searching in the settings of VSCode, I found that you can change the path of your include in `c_cpp_properties.json` file that you can find in your `.vscode` folder

Adding the path you want in the `includePath` field allow you to choose your own include path

Answer (score 2):

I want to add that you can also use the `.vscode/settings.json` file as an alternative to `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`.

For example, I just set up a project with this:

```
{
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_path": "/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang-format",
  "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "~/.conan/data/**"
  ],
}
```