Visual Studio Code + Conan 1: includePath not resolving third party libraries
I have jumped into an existing project where conan 1 and cmake are used and I am trying to get visual studio code setup in a way that code navigation works as best as it could. conan 1 is deprecated now. migrating is on its way but not done yet, tho I am not sure if it matters for this.
Appearently it should be enough to add
"includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "~/.conan/data/**"]
to the c_cpp_properties.json like this SO anwser suggests https://stackoverflow.com/a/60460921 Unfortunately this does not work for me. Third party libraries are still not found and the underlying conan folder structure is confusing to me. I do see why it probably can't work, but I have no idea how to do it right. Within my user profile folder the structure is this
C:\<user>\.conan\data\boost\<version>\jenkins\stable\package\<hash>\
Two issues I see here: 1) there are multiple versions available for some libraries and that would obviously cause a conflict for the header names if vs code would resolve this correctly and 2) inside such a folder is a .conan_link file which contains the correct path to where the headers are actually located. However I am not aware vs code goes as far as this and looks inside this file to resolve the path, does it?
Bottom line is this does not work at all for me and I feel very dumb. Id be happy about any information that shines some light on this subject and helps me understand better. Surely this must be possible to do, but I could not find a working solution yet.

This depends highly on the VS code integration, if using the standard cmake-tools extension for example. It would be good to have the full details, also for support-like conversation, better submit a ticket with the details to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Thanks for the reply. My extensions are pretty standard. That includes the standard cmake-tools extension from microsoft. Since no extensions where mentioned in the referenced SO post I figured that'll be no issue. Ill ask the conan guys on github tho and hopefully ill be able to update this post afterwards with a soltion :).
